# RTL8812AU Usb adapter driver issues

Tags: wireless, 17.10, realtek-wireless

lsusb relevant output `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter`

Upon plugging the device it is recognized by lsusb, however when I go to wireless settings no adapter is recognized. The driver is installed (by going to software and updates -> addition drivers and selecting the open source driver).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Comment: Worked for me on Linux Mint 19.3 (Ubuntu 18.04.) Didn't even have to reboot.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Needed to reboot. A later version (4.3.8) did not work.

Comment: doesn't work on Ubuntu 21

Comment: @MykolaVeriga Please start your own new question and we'll be happy to help.