# Setup for OURLINK USB Wireless stopped working

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point

I bought one of the little cheap wirless usb sticks.  Ubunbu would not find it and a kind person on this site supplied a script for setup.  I had to run this after most or all reboots.  I went through the procedure today.  It produces errors and longer works.  Any suggestions?

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd  rtl8812AU
make clean
make
make install
modprobe 8812au

**bin bash**
#!/bin/bash
#
# Copyright (c) 2012
#
# Authors: Wild Man, Krytarik
# Helpers: chili555
#
# This script gathers the infos necessary for troubleshooting a wireless
# connection and saves them in a text file, wrapping it in an archive if it
# exceeds the 19.5 kB size limit for ".txt" attachments on the Ubuntu Forums.
#
##############################################################################
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#

SCRIPTDATE="2017-03-25 08:04 +0100"
FILEBASE="wireless-info"
OUTPUTDIR="$PWD"
OUTPUTDIRFB="/tmp"

MODMATCHES="(air|ar5|at7|ath[^3]?|b43|bcma|brcm|carl|ipw|iwl|ndis|r(818|8192[eu]|871|92su)|8(188|189|192|723|812)[acde][esu]|rt[23567]|rtl|ssb|wl|(cfg|mac)80211)"
LSMODMATCHES="(wmi|(dell|ideapad)[-_]laptop)"
IFACEMATCHES="(wlan[0-9]|eth[0-9])"
DMESGMATCHES="(firmware|[nN]etwork)"
NMPROFMATCHES="\(\[connection\]\|id=\|type=\|permissions=\|autoconnect=\|\[802-11-wireless\]\|\[wifi\]\|ssid=\|bssid=\|mac-address\(-blacklist\)\?=\|mtu=\|\[802-1x\]\|[[:graph:]]*ca-certs\?=\|\[ipv[46]\]\|method=\)"

DMESGEXCL="apparmor|(cfg|mac)80211"
MODINFOEXCL="alias"
MODPROBEXCL="(alsa-base|blacklist-(firewire|framebuffer|modem|oss|watchdog)|fglrx|nvidia|fbdev|bumblebee)"
PMUTILSEXCL="/etc/pm/(power.d/(95hdparm-apm|intel-audio-powersave|sata_alpm)|sleep.d/(10_grub-common|10_unattended-upgrades.*|novatel_3g.*))"

NETMGRNAMES=("NetworkManager" "Wicd" "ConnMan")
NETMGRPATHS=("/usr/sbin/NetworkManager" "/usr/sbin/wicd" "/usr/sbin/connmand")
DEC2BI=({0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1}{0..1})
DEC2HEX=($(printf "%02x " {0..255}))

export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

if [ -t 0 ]; then
    DIALOGAPP="terminal"
    DIALOGBREAK=" "
    TERMOUT="yes"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/zenity ]; then
    DIALOGAPP="zenity"
    DIALOGBREAK="\n"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/kdialog ]; then
    DIALOGAPP="kdialog"
    DIALOGBREAK="\n"
else
    exit 1
fi

if [ -t 0 ]; then
    SUDO="sudo"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/pkexec ]; then
    SUDO="pkexec"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/gksudo ]; then
    SUDO="gksudo"
    GKSUDO="yes"
elif [ -x /usr/bin/kdesudo ]; then
    SUDO="kdesudo"
    KDESUDO="yes"
    KDESUDOCMT=" needs administrative privileges. Please enter your password."
fi

dialog_info () {
    case $DIALOGAPP in
    terminal)
        printf "%b\n" "$1"
        ;;
    zenity)
        zenity --info --text="$1"
        ;;
    kdialog)
        kdialog --msgbox "$1"
        ;;
    esac
}

dialog_error () {
    case $DIALOGAPP in
    terminal)
        printf "%b\n" "$1" >&2
        ;;
    zenity)
        zenity --error --text="$1"
        ;;
    kdialog)
        kdialog --error "$1"
        ;;
    esac
}

dialog_question () {
    case $DIALOGAPP in
    terminal)
        local INPUT
        read -r -p "$1 [Y/n]: " INPUT
        echo "${INPUT,,}"
        ;;
    zenity)
        zenity --question --text="$1" || echo "no"
        ;;
    kdialog)
        kdialog --yesno "$1" || echo "no"
        ;;
    esac
}

ip6-mac () {
    for MAC in "$@"; do
    OCT1BI=${DEC2BI[0x${MAC:0:2}]}
    OCT1BI7=$((${OCT1BI:6:1} - 1))
    OCT1BIM="${OCT1BI:0:6}${OCT1BI7#-}${OCT1BI:7}"
    IP6S+=${IP6S:+$'\n'}"${DEC2HEX[2#$OCT1BIM]}${MAC:3:2}:${MAC:6:2}ff:fe${MAC:9:2}:${MAC:12:2}${MAC:15:2}"
    done
    sed 's/\(^\|:\)0\+\([[:alnum:]]\)/\1\2/g;s/^\([0:]\+\)/\\(::\\|\1\\)/' <<< "$IP6S"
}

exec 3>&1 4>&2
exec 1> "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt" || {
    dialog_error "${TERMOUT+\n}Cannot write output file in \"$OUTPUTDIR\",${DIALOGBREAK}trying in \"$OUTPUTDIRFB\" instead.${TERMOUT+\n}"
    OUTPUTDIR="$OUTPUTDIRFB"
    exec 1> "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt" || {
    dialog_error "${TERMOUT+\n}Cannot write output file in \"$OUTPUTDIR\" either, aborting.${TERMOUT+\n}"
    exit 1
    }
}
exec 2>&1

printf "\n########## wireless info START ##########\n\n"
REPORTDATE=$(date +"%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z %z")
SCRIPTDATE=$(date -u -d "$SCRIPTDATE" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z %z")
LASTBOOTDT=$(last -FRn 1 reboot | sed -n 's/.*system boot[ ]\+\(.\+\) - .*/\1/p')
LASTBOOTDT=$(date -d "$LASTBOOTDT" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z %z")
printf "Report from: %s\n\n" "$REPORTDATE"
printf "Booted last: %s\n\n" "$LASTBOOTDT"
printf "Script from: %s\n" "$SCRIPTDATE"

printf "\n##### release ###########################\n\n"
lsb_release -idrc

printf "\n##### kernel ############################\n\n"
uname -srvmpio
echo
sed 's/root=[^ ]*//;s/[ ]\+/, /g;s/^BOOT_IMAGE=[^ ]*/Parameters:/' /proc/cmdline

printf "\n##### desktop ###########################\n\n"
if [ -n "$DESKTOP_SESSION" ]; then
    DESKTOP="$DESKTOP_SESSION"
else
    DESKTOP=$(sed -n 's/^Session=\(.\+\)$/\1/p' "$HOME/.dmrc")
    DESKDMRC=" (from ~/.dmrc)"
fi
if [ -n "$DESKTOP" ]; then
    if [ -f "/usr/share/xsessions/$DESKTOP.desktop" ]; then
    DESKTOP=$(sed -n 's/^Name=\(.\+\)$/\1/p' "/usr/share/xsessions/$DESKTOP.desktop")
    fi
    echo "${DESKTOP/ Session/}${DESKDMRC}"
else
    printf "\nCould not be determined.\n"
fi

printf "\n##### lspci #############################\n\n"
lspci -nnk | grep -iA 2 '^[^[:space:]].*net' | sed '/^--$/d; /^[^[:space:]]/ i\\'

printf "\n##### lsusb #############################\n\n"
lsusb

printf "\n##### PCMCIA card info ##################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/pccardctl ]; then
    pccardctl info
else
    echo "'pccardctl' is not installed (package \"pcmciautils\")."
fi

printf "\n##### rfkill ############################\n\n"
rfkill list all

printf "\n##### lsmod #############################\n\n"
LSMOD=$(lsmod | egrep "(^|[[:punct:] ])($MODMATCHES|$LSMODMATCHES)[^[:punct:] ]*([[:punct:] ]|$)")
echo "$LSMOD"

printf "\n##### interfaces ########################\n\n"
sed '/^#/d;s/^wpa-psk [[:graph:]]\+/wpa-psk <WPA key removed>/' /etc/network/interfaces

printf "\n##### ifconfig ##########################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/ifconfig ]; then
    IFCONFIG=$(ifconfig -a)
else
    IFCONFIG=$(ip address show)
fi
echo "$IFCONFIG"
IFCONFIG=$(sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${g;s/\n /\\ /g;p}' <<< "$IFCONFIG")
IFACESETH=($(sed -n 's/^\([^ ]\+\)[ ]\+Link encap:Ethernet.*/\1/p; s#^[0-9]\+: \([^ :]\+\):.* link/ether.*#\1#p' <<< "$IFCONFIG"))
if (( ${#IFACESETH[@]} > 0 )); then
    IFETHMATCHES=${IFACESETH[@]}
    IFACEMATCHES="($IFACEMATCHES|(${IFETHMATCHES// /|}))"
fi

printf "\n##### iwconfig ##########################\n\n"
iwconfig

printf "\n##### route #############################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/route ]; then
    route -n
else
    ip route show
fi

printf "\n##### resolv.conf #######################\n\n"
grep -v '^#' /etc/resolv.conf

printf "\n##### network managers ##################\n\n"
printf "Installed:\n\n"
for NETMGRNR in "${!NETMGRPATHS[@]}"; do
    if [ -f "${NETMGRPATHS[$NETMGRNR]}" ]; then
    NETMGRINST+=("${NETMGRNAMES[$NETMGRNR]}")
    fi
done
printf "\t%s\n" "${NETMGRINST[@]:-None found.}"
NETMGRMATCHES=${NETMGRPATHS[@]/#*\//|}
NETMGRMATCHES=${NETMGRMATCHES// |/|}
NETMGRMATCHES="(${NETMGRMATCHES#|})"
printf "\nRunning:\n\n"
ps -ef | egrep "( |/)$NETMGRMATCHES($| )" || printf "\tNone found.\n"

printf "\n##### NetworkManager info ###############\n\n"
if [ -x /usr/bin/nm-tool ]; then
    nm-tool
elif [ -x /usr/bin/nmcli ]; then
    nmcli -f all device show | sed '/^GENERAL.DEVICE:[ ]\+lo$/,/^$/d; /^AP\[[0-9]\+\]\./d'
    echo
    nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,MODE,CHAN,FREQ,RATE,SIGNAL,BARS,SECURITY,ACTIVE,IN-USE device wifi list
else
    echo "NetworkManager is not installed (package \"network-manager\")."
fi

printf "\n##### NetworkManager.state ##############\n\n"
cat -s /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state

printf "\n##### NetworkManager.conf ###############\n\n"
grep -v '^#' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
if [ -f /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf ]; then
    printf "\nnm-system-settings.conf (used up to Ubuntu 10.04):\n\n"
    grep -v '^#' /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf
fi

printf "\n##### NetworkManager profiles ###########\n\n"
if [ -d /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections ]; then
    if [ -n "$SUDO" ]; then
    trap "" 2 3
    NMPROFILES=$(find /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec $SUDO${GKSUDO+ -D grep --}${KDESUDO+ -d --comment "<b>grep</b>$KDESUDOCMT" --} grep -vH '^$' {} +) && SUDOSUCCESS="yes" || SUDOSUCCESS="no"
    trap 2 3
    if [ "$SUDOSUCCESS" = "yes" ]; then
        ORIGIFS="$IFS"
        IFS=$'\n'
        for NMWLPRFFILE in $(sed -n 's/^\(.\+\):type=\(802-11-wireless\|wifi\).*$/\1/p' <<< "$NMPROFILES"); do
        NMWLPRFFLPERMS=$(stat -c "%a %U" "$NMWLPRFFILE")
        NMWLPROFILE=($(sed -n "s;^$NMWLPRFFILE:\($NMPROFMATCHES.*\)$;\1 |;p" <<< "$NMPROFILES"))
        NMWLPROFSOUT+="[[$NMWLPRFFILE]] ($NMWLPRFFLPERMS)"$'\n'"${NMWLPROFILE[@]}"$'\n\n'
        done
        IFS="$ORIGIFS"
        sed 's# | \[#\n\[#g;s#\] |#\]#g;s/ |$//' <<< "$NMWLPROFSOUT" | sed '/^\[[^]]*\]$/d'
    else
        printf "\nAcquisition of admin privileges failed.\n"
    fi
    else
    echo "No way to acquire admin privileges found."
    fi
else
    echo "No NetworkManager profiles found."
fi

printf "\n##### iw reg get ########################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/iw ]; then
    if IWREGGET=$(iw reg get 2>&1) && [ -f /etc/timezone ]; then
    REGION=$(cat /etc/timezone)
    printf "Region: %s (based on set time zone)\n\n" "$REGION"
    fi
    echo "$IWREGGET"
else
    echo "'iw' is not installed (package \"iw\")."
fi

printf "\n##### iwlist channels ###################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/iwlist ]; then
    iwlist chan
else
    echo "'iwlist' is not installed (package \"wireless-tools\")."
fi

printf "\n##### iwlist scan #######################\n\n"
if [ -x /sbin/iwlist ]; then
    if [ -n "$SUDO" ]; then
    trap "" 2 3
    IWLISTSCAN=$($SUDO${KDESUDO+ -d} iwlist scan) && SUDOSUCCESS="yes" || SUDOSUCCESS="no"
    trap 2 3
    if [ "$SUDOSUCCESS" = "yes" ]; then
        if [[ $IWLISTSCAN = *Frequency:* ]]; then
        printf "Channel occupancy:\n\n"
        grep '^[ ]*Frequency:' <<< "$IWLISTSCAN" | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^[ ]\+\([ ][0-9]\+\)[ ]\+/     \1   APs on   /'
        echo
        fi
        grep -v '^[ ]*IE: Unknown:' <<< "$IWLISTSCAN"
    else
        printf "\nAcquisition of admin privileges failed.\n"
    fi
    else
    echo "No way to acquire admin privileges found."
    fi
else
    echo "'iwlist' is not installed (package \"wireless-tools\")."
fi

printf "\n##### module infos ######################\n\n"
MODULES=$(egrep -o "^$MODMATCHES[^ ]*" <<< "$LSMOD")
for MODULE in $MODULES; do
    MODINFO=$(modinfo $MODULE | egrep -v "^$MODINFOEXCL:")
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$MODULE" "$MODINFO"
done

printf "\n##### module parameters #################\n\n"
for MODULE in $MODULES; do
    if [ -d /sys/module/$MODULE/parameters ]; then
    MODPARAMS=$(grep -H '^[[:graph:]]' /sys/module/$MODULE/parameters/* | sed 's#^.*/##;s/:/: /')
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$MODULE" "$MODPARAMS"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### /etc/modules ######################\n\n"
grep -v '^#' /etc/modules

printf "\n##### modprobe options ##################\n\n"
for MODPROBEFILE in $(find /etc/modprobe.{conf,d} -name "*.conf" -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex ".*$MODPROBEXCL.*" 2> /dev/null | sort); do
    MODPROBEOPTS=$(egrep -v '^(#|$)' $MODPROBEFILE)
    if [ -n "$MODPROBEOPTS" ]; then
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$MODPROBEFILE" "$MODPROBEOPTS"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### rc.local ##########################\n\n"
grep -v '^#' /etc/rc.local

printf "\n##### pm-utils ##########################\n\n"
for PMUTILSFILE in $(find /etc/pm/*.d \( -type f -o -type l \) -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex "$PMUTILSEXCL" | sort); do
    PMUTFLCONT=$(egrep -v '^(#|$)' $PMUTILSFILE)
    if [ -n "$PMUTFLCONT" ]; then
    PMUTFLPERMS=$(stat -c "%a %U" $PMUTILSFILE)
    printf "[%s] (%s)\n%s\n\n" "$PMUTILSFILE" "$PMUTFLPERMS" "$PMUTFLCONT"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### udev rules ########################\n\n"
for UDEVRLFILE in $(find /etc/udev/rules.d -name "*net*.rules" | sort); do
    UDEVRULES=$(grep -B1 '^[^#]' $UDEVRLFILE | egrep -v '^(--)?$')
    if [ -n "$UDEVRULES" ]; then
    printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$UDEVRLFILE" "$UDEVRULES"
    fi
done

printf "\n##### dmesg #############################\n\n"
dmesg | tail -n 100 | egrep "[[:punct:] ]($MODMATCHES|$IFACEMATCHES|$DMESGMATCHES)[^[:punct:] ]*[[:punct:] ]" | egrep -v "$DMESGEXCL" | uniq -cf 2 | sed 's/^[ ]\+1[ ]\+//;s/^[ ]\+\([0-9]\+\)[ ]\+\(.\+\)$/\2 (repeated \1 times)/'

printf "\n########## wireless info END ############\n\n"

exec 2>&4 4>&-
exec 1>&3 3>&-

##### MAC address masking #####

RESULTS=$(cat -s "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt")$'\n'

ORIGIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

IFACESIDS=($(sed -n "/\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[[:alnum:]]\{2\}/ {/\(00:\)\{5\}00/! {s/^\([^ ]\+\)[ ]\+.*HWaddr.*/'\1'/p; s/^[0-9]\+: \([^ :]\+\):.*/'\1'/p}}" <<< "$IFCONFIG"))
IFACESMACS=($(sed -n '/\(00:\)\{5\}00/! s#.*\(HWaddr\|link/[^ ]\+\) \(\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[[:alnum:]]\{2\}\).*#\2#p' <<< "$IFCONFIG"))
IFACESIP6S=($(ip6-mac "${IFACESMACS[@]}"))

WLAPSIWLIDS=($(sed -n "/^[ ]*Cell [0-9]\+/,/^[ ]*ESSID:/ {/^[ ]*Cell [0-9]\+/h; /^[ ]*ESSID:/ {H;g;s/^[ ]*Cell 0\?\([0-9]\+\).*ESSID:\"\(.*\)\"$/'\2' [AC\1]/p}}" <<< "$IWLISTSCAN"))
WLAPSIWLMACS=($(sed -n 's/^[ ]*Cell [0-9]\+.*Address: \([^ ]\+\)/\1/p' <<< "$IWLISTSCAN"))
WLAPSIWLIP6S=($(ip6-mac "${WLAPSIWLMACS[@]}"))

WLAPSNMRAW=$(sed -n '/^##### NetworkManager info #####/,/^##### / {/^[ ]*Wireless Access Points/,/^$/ {/Wireless Access Points/d;s/^[ ]\+\*\?//;s/:[ ]\+/\t/;p}; /^SSID[ ]\+BSSID[ ]\+/,/^$/ {/^SSID[ ]\{2,\}BSSID[ ]\{2,\}/d;s/[ ]\{2,\}/\t/;p}}' <<< "$RESULTS")
WLAPSNMIDS=($(awk -F '\t' '{print "'\''" $1 "'\''"}' <<< "$WLAPSNMRAW"))
WLAPSNMMACS=($(grep -o '\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[[:alnum:]]\{2\}' <<< "$WLAPSNMRAW"))
WLAPSNMIP6S=($(ip6-mac "${WLAPSNMMACS[@]}"))

IFS="$ORIGIFS"

for IFACENR in "${!IFACESMACS[@]}"; do
    MACMASKSED+="s;${IFACESMACS[$IFACENR]};<MAC ${IFACESIDS[$IFACENR]} [IF$(($IFACENR + 1))]>;I;"
    MACMASKSED+=" /${IFACESIP6S[$IFACENR]}/ s;${IFACESIP6S[$IFACENR]/#\\(::/\(};<IP6 ${IFACESIDS[$IFACENR]} [IF$(($IFACENR + 1))]>;I;"
    IFACEMACC=${IFACESMACS[$IFACENR]//:/}
    if [[ ${IFACESIDS[$IFACENR],,} =~ ${IFACEMACC,,} ]]; then
    MACMASKSED+="s;\(${IFACESIDS[$IFACENR]:1:3}\)$IFACEMACC;\1<IF from MAC [IF$(($IFACENR + 1))]>;Ig;"
    fi
done

for WLAPIWLNR in "${!WLAPSIWLMACS[@]}"; do
    MACMASKSED+="s;${WLAPSIWLMACS[$WLAPIWLNR]};<MAC ${WLAPSIWLIDS[$WLAPIWLNR]}>;I;"
    MACMASKSED+=" /${WLAPSIWLIP6S[$WLAPIWLNR]}/ s;${WLAPSIWLIP6S[$WLAPIWLNR]/#\\(::/\(};<IP6 ${WLAPSIWLIDS[$WLAPIWLNR]}>;I;"
done

for WLAPNMNR in "${!WLAPSNMMACS[@]}"; do
    MACMASKSED+="s;${WLAPSNMMACS[$WLAPNMNR]};<MAC ${WLAPSNMIDS[$WLAPNMNR]} [AN$(($WLAPNMNR + 1))]>;I;"
    MACMASKSED+=" /${WLAPSNMIP6S[$WLAPNMNR]}/ s;${WLAPSNMIP6S[$WLAPNMNR]/#\\(::/\(};<IP6 ${WLAPSNMIDS[$WLAPNMNR]} [AN$(($WLAPNMNR + 1))]>;I;"
done

sed "$MACMASKSED /\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{6,\}/! s/\([[:alnum:]]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[[:alnum:]]\{2\}/<MAC address>/" <<< "$RESULTS" > "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt"

##### The End #####

dialog_info "${TERMOUT+\n}Results saved in \"$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt\".${TERMOUT+\n}"

if (( $(stat -c %s "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt") > 19968 )); then
    tar -czf "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.tar.gz" -C "$OUTPUTDIR" "$FILEBASE.txt" && \
    dialog_info "Results also archived in \"$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.tar.gz\",${DIALOGBREAK}as they exceed the 19.5 kB size limit for \".txt\" attachments${DIALOGBREAK}on the Ubuntu Forums.${TERMOUT+\n}" || \
    dialog_error "Results exceed the 19.5 kB size limit for \".txt\" attachments${DIALOGBREAK}on the Ubuntu Forums, but archive could not be created.${TERMOUT+\n}"
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/pastebinit ] && ping -nc 3 -w 6 -i 0.2 paste.ubuntu.com > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    PASTEBIN=$(dialog_question "Do you also want to post them${DIALOGBREAK}to your default 'pastebinit' provider?")
    if [[ ! $PASTEBIN =~ ^no?$ ]]; then
    PASTERESULT=$(pastebinit -i "$OUTPUTDIR/$FILEBASE.txt" -f text 2>&1) && PASTESUCCESS="yes"
    if [ "$PASTESUCCESS" = "yes" ]; then
        dialog_info "${TERMOUT+\n}Pastebin successful:\n\n${PASTERESULT}${TERMOUT+\n}"
    else
        if [ -n "$PASTERESULT" ]; then
        dialog_error "${TERMOUT+\n}Pastebin failed, error message is:\n\n${PASTERESULT}${TERMOUT+\n}"
        else
        dialog_error "${TERMOUT+\n}Pastebin failed, no error message given.${TERMOUT+\n}"
        fi
    fi
    else
    echo
    fi
fi
```

**Result**

```
dan@Pavilion:~$ sudo ./sudoWIFI.sh
[sudo] password for dan:
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/led ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/build M=/home/dan/rtl8812AU  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/dan/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/dan/rtl8812AU/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
                 from /home/dan/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/dan/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/dan/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h:343:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  allow_signal(SIGTERM);
  ^
/home/dan/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/home/dan/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h:353:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (signal_pending (current))
      ^
/home/dan/rtl8812AU/include/osdep_service.h:355:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   flush_signals(current);
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/home/dan/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/dan/rtl8812AU/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/home/dan/rtl8812AU' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/dan/rtl8812AU] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic'
Makefile:1576: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
install -p -m 644 8812au.ko  /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat '8812au.ko': No such file or directory
Makefile:1582: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic
```

Comment: Looking at this from another direction, is there a list of wireless adapters that are supported natively in Ubuntu.  I just looked at Frys and non said Ubuntu compatible.  Some say Linux compatible but the one I have says that too.  This is for a desktop so a n internal card works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you undertake the process in my answer here: [RTL8812AU Usb adapter driver issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991643/rtl8812au-usb-adapter-driver-issues) It will compile and install without errors in kernel 4.13.0-32 and, most likely, newer. It installed cleanly on my own system using the exact same kernel.

Because it uses the *dkms* process, it will not need to be re-installed after kernel upgrades.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  The only deviation was that I got a warning dkms is currently not installed followed by the command to install. I ran that command and continued.  The system seemed a little confused because it then had both wired and wireless or maybe the router was confused.  I disconnected wire and rebooted.  Thanks.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour