# Setup for OURLINK USB Wireless stopped working - Again

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I have one of these and it stopped working again.  It seems to be the latest Ubuntu update that got it.  Neither of the earlier solutions work so I have to go back to the earlier version of Ubuntu.  Are there any recommendations to fix or maybe a recommendation for a wireless adapter for desktop more compatible with updates?

see for earlier experience
[Setup for OURLINK USB Wireless stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002420/setup-for-ourlink-usb-wireless-stopped-working)

More detail from the non working version. 4.13.0-45 works.  I'm also getting a system error but it seem unrelated.  See pics.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01SDm.png)[image]

dan@Pavilion:~$ sudo dkms status

[sudo] password for dan:

rtl8812au, 4.2.2, 4.13.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed

dan@Pavilion:~$

dan@Pavilion:~$ uname -r

4.15.0-24-generic

dan@Pavilion:~$

[image: error detail]

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo dkms status` and also: `uname -r`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:
https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au/issues/144

1: git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au
2: cd rtl8812au
3: wget https://github.com/msharov/rtl8812au/commit/296fb88cf466fe07fffd1b9d2f42a33c420ceb1d.patch

4: patch -p1 < *.patch
5: sudo make && sudo make install