# Should I remove old Wifi adapter driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

My last adapter uses `rtl8812au` so I installed from a Github repo and added it to dkms. I just got a new adapter that uses `rtl88x2bu` driver. I found that driver on Github so I installed it. Currently I have both adapters plugged in because I needed internet to install the new driver. Since I'm not going to use the old adapter anymore, do I need to uninstall the old driver from dkms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to uninstall the old driver unless it's causing issues.
If you want to uninstall the old driver to clean up your system, I would try this command

```
dkms status
```

You may see some results like this:

```
8812au, 4.2.2, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.77, 4.15.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.77, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.2.2, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64
```

From here you can see which drivers are installed, so remove them by typing 
(Replace 4.2.2 with your versions)

```
sudo dkms remove 8812au/4.2.2 --all
sudo dkms remove rtl8812au/4.2.2 --all
sudo dkms remove rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg --all
```

Here's an answer I found that may help you:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1104342/1029522

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't cause any problem so I'll just leave it.