# USB WiFi adaptor - unable to install

Tags: wireless, usb

I am trying to install a new usb adaptor that has linux drivers on a cd that comes in the box.  The installation doc is unhelpful and just says run 'install.sh' which I have tried to do using bash ./install.sh but I get a load of 'Cannot mkdir: Read -only file system' errors.  I assume that is because it's trying to make directories on the CD ROM drive.  So I copy all of the contents of the CD to the desktop and run bash ./install again.  This time it runs through the script OK but then it says:

I have figured out how to change the root password and now when I run the install.sh script a whole series of errors ending in:

Compile make driver error: 2

I have read so many articles on troubleshooting, most (bizarrely) require an internet connection which I don't have!

I am Ubuntu 18.04 and the chipset is rtl8821AU

Please help :)

Comment: You'd better search for a solution. In most cases the drivers coming with Realtek dongles are too old to be installed on modern Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RTL8812AU Usb adapter driver issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991643/rtl8812au-usb-adapter-driver-issues)

Comment: Hi Pilot...not a duplicate.  That post assumes an internet connection.

Comment: You can find lot's of other posts,

Comment: And you can always get a temporary internet connection, e.g by using your phone.

Comment: @Pilot...I know.  I've been reading them for 2 days.  No luck with any of them yet.

Comment: Oh...interesting.  How can I connect via my phone?

Comment: If you have an Android phone, connect it to USB and enable USB modem in the phone when asked. Or using the menu if not asked,

Comment: @Pilot excellent, I'm connected.  Thank you!