# 19.10: Problem using USB WiFi adapter with RTL8812AU

Tags: realtek-wireless

Buongiorno,
riscontro un problema con l'utilizzo della mia chiavetta usb wifi, ovvero ho installato il driver tramite l'applicazione driver aggiuntivi ma non funziona. Ho provato a cercare dappertutto sul web e ho provato decine di soluzioni ma non ho risolto
la mia scheda è: Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac 2T2R DB WLAN Adapter
Sapete come aiutarmi?
Grazie

Google translate:
Hello, I have a problem with the use of my wifi usb stick, that is, I installed the driver through the application additional drivers but it does not work. I tried to search everywhere on the web and I have tried dozens of solutions but I have not solved my card is: Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a / b / g / n / ac 2T2R DB WLAN Adapter Do you know how to help me? Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: A solution is found, thanks to the info you provided with help from chili555. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/991643/rtl8812au-usb-adapter-driver-issues/991650#991650

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RTL8812AU Usb adapter driver issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991643/rtl8812au-usb-adapter-driver-issues)